# Embedding an SVG document inside an SVG document, but maintaining accessibility

Tags: java, image, svg, embed, batik

I need to include an SVG document (actually 3) inside another SVG document for the purpose of scrolling the embedded SVG document.

I use a [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) `JSVGCanvas` to display it inside a Java application. Since putting that canvas into a `JScrollPane` and setting the size of the canvas to a very large size consumes huge amounts of memory (`JSVGCanvas` doesn't seem to be any memory-efficient), I thought about reducing the visible part of the SVG by using the viewBox attribute and using [SVG Scrollbars](http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/scrollbar/) to scroll inside the document.

But it seems that embedding an SVG inside an SVG via `<image>` tag only imports that document as an image, not as another SVG document. Not even the `<desc>` or `<title>` tags are evaluated to provide tooltips on elements. I also need dynamic functionality in the embedded SVG (some elements must be clickable and I provide handlers for those clicks in the java application). Also I need to modify the embedded SVGs DOM on runtime. I don't have an idea how to access the embedded SVG from within Batik.

It seems that all of this is not possible. Am I misinterpreting the `<image>` tag? Is there another way to embed an SVG document inside another SVG document while maintaining the dynamic functionality?

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                  upper embedded SVG                       ||
 ||                                                           ||
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                  lower embedded SVG                       ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 ||                                                           ||
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 ||<               horizontal scrollbar                      >||
 |+-----------------------------------------------------------+|
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The scrollbar should scroll the viewBox of the upper and the lower embedded SVG. But I still need to access those documents to modify their DOMs and the need to be dynamic (react on mouseover, click, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an `<image>` to embed the other SVGs.  It is legal to have one `<svg>` inside another.  For example:

```
<svg>
  <svg id="upper">
     ...etc...
  </svg>
  <svg id="lower" y="200px">
     ...etc...
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Ah! Yes, of course you are right. That is a much better way. And I dont not need outsource the contents of the inner SVGs, which is even more preferable.